# The UTD Top 100 Business School Research Rankings

Tags: publications, phd, advisor, business-school, management

I am planning to apply for a Ph.D. in management, and I am using The UTD Top 100 Business School Research Rankings to create my university list ( I only selected the journals related to my field). I appreciate it if you let me know whether it's a good approach and also what factors are critical to have a better placement; Advisor, University ranking (if yes, which ranking?), published papers?
Thanks